# Hide Cursor on being moveless for certain amount of time and show it again on move

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to hide the cursor after a certain time (if the mouse is not moving), and I want to show the cursor when I move the mouse in a picturebox. I just can't get it to work... This is what I have tried:

```
    // this Never seem to hide the cursor
    private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Show();
        tim.Stop();
        tim.Start();
    }
    private void tim_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
        tim.Stop();
    }
```

-

```
    // works but in this case I want cursor.ico to be a resource
    private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        tim.Stop();
        tim.Start();
    }
    private void tim_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = new Cursor("cursor.ico");
        tim.Stop();
    }
```

-

```
    // Properties.Resources.cursor gives an error even though I added it to my resources
    // cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Icon' to 'System.IntPtr'
    private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        tim.Stop();
        tim.Start();
    }
    private void tim_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.cursor);
        tim.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: For the error: you need to use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cyw4de71(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor overload. I actually never used the `Cursor.Current` property, I always set the form's `Cursor` property directly like `this.Cursor = Cursors.Default`, but am not sure what's the difference.

Comment: Oh I don't know why I had ".Current", worked fine without too. But about the constructor, did you mean this line: this.Cursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "MyCursor.cur");? Because that did not work, and I don't want a MyCursor.cur beside my application.

Comment: I just tried around a little with debug messages in the two handlers: maybe my mouse is broken, but I get a `MouseMove` event almost every second without actually moving the mouse at all... maybe that's part of your problem...

Comment: Well Cursor.Current = new Cursor("cursor.ico"); seems to work. Is there any way I can do that like a resource instead? I don't want a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a timer and handle its `Tick` event. In the `Tick` event, check if the last movement of the mouse was before the certain time, then hide the cursor using `Cursor.Hide()`. Also handle `MouseMove` of the `PictureBox` and show the cursor using `Cursor.Show()` method.

*Note:* Don't forget to enable the timer and set `Interval` of timer to a short value, for example `300` and change `duration` value in the following code, for a shorter/longer inactive time:

```
DateTime? lastMovement;
bool hidden = false;
int duration = 2;
void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lastMovement = DateTime.Now;
    if (hidden)
    {
        Cursor.Show();
        hidden = false;
    }
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!lastMovement.HasValue)
        return;
    TimeSpan elaped = DateTime.Now - lastMovement.Value;
    if (elaped >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration) && !hidden)
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
        hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is the duration = 2? Is that 2 seconds? But isn't the time set in the timer interval?

Comment: Set interval to a short time, like `300` milliseconds. `duration` is the inactive time.